# Where I was or where I were?

Tags: grammaticality

This question came up to me when I was watching this interview video : https://youtu.be/5sNWXJnKYxc?t=251

Left: "Dan knows where I was. Where ... where I was? Where I were?"

Why did he switch to use "where I where" instead of "where I was"?

Edit:
I know that in that sentence, he should've used "where I was". I'm simply confused on why a native speaker would say "where I were".

Comment: "Where I was" is correct.  Maybe he was being silly.

Comment: I was, you were, he was, they were.  English is simple, no?

Comment: Hmm. I also think "I was" is the correct one. Though what confuses me is that that guy in the video is a native speaker and so I was just wondering if maybe there's a legitimate use of "where I were"

Comment: @christ Not sure why this question is considered as off-topic. As this question is simply asking on the unusual choice of grammar used by a native speaker in the interview. As such, there's not much I can do for "include research" though I can add more context to the question

Comment: It's actually impossible to tell because he doesn't finish talking.  It could be he was going to say something like, "Dan knows where(ever) I were shooting, I'd make it work."  That's an awkward construction, but it's not ungrammatical because it uses the subjunctive to express hypothetically going to a place or places, even all places anywhere.  Using "were" there could mean that every possible place he could go to film, not places he's actually going to, he would be successful in that endeavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct conjugation of "to be" in first person singular, past tense, is "I was". Therefore, "Where I was" is correct and "Where I were" is incorrect.

The confusion may arise from the present tense of regular English verbs taking on a similar form to the plural persons (which is "were" in the case of "to be"). For example, for the regular verb "to look", we have all of the plural forms (we, you, they) as well as the first-person singular (I) taking on the form "look" and the third-person plural forms (he, she, it) taking on the form "looks".

For information regarding why present-tense conjugation of verbs in the first-person singular is similar to the plural persons, see Grammar Girl's ["Why does 'I' Take Plural Verbs?"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/why-does-i-take-plural-verbs)

Conjugation of "to be": [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=be&oldid=53825397#Conjugation), [Reverso](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-be.html)